# Indexing Matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

I have a matrix that is created using four indices i,j,k, and l. I use the following scheme to create the matrix,

```
for i = 1:N
 for j = 1:2
  for k = 1:2
   for l = 1:N
    Matrix(l,2(j+2*i-3)+k) = Value
   end
  end
 end
end
```

When I do this it produces a matrix that changes as follows:

```
                              Columns
         i = 1  i = 1  i = 1  i = 1  i = 2  i = 2  i = 2  i = 2 ...   
         j = 1  j = 1  j = 2  j = 2  j = 1  j = 1  j = 2  j = 2 ...
         k = 1  k = 2  k = 1  k = 2  k = 1  k = 2  k = 1  k = 2 ...
l = 1
l = 2
  .
  .
  .
```

Unfortunately I indexed it wrong and need to change it. I don't want change any of the calculations. I need a code that will change the above matrix into the following:

```
                               Columns
             l = 1  l = 1  l = 2  l = 2  l = 1  l = 1  l = 2  l = 2 ...   
             k = 1  k = 2  k = 1  k = 2  k = 1  k = 2  k = 1  k = 2 ...
i = 1  j = 1               
i = 1  j = 2              
i = 2  j = 1   
i = 2  j = 2    
      .
      .  
      .
```

In other words a code that will look like,

```
for i = 1:N
 for j = 1:2
  for k = 1:2
   for l = 1:N
    Matrix(New Index) = Matrix(Old Index)
   end
  end
 end
end
```

How do I do this? Thanks.

Comment: I guess there is a good reason, why you dont want to just run the code again but with the right indices?

Comment: Yes their is. The calculations are complicated and involve superposition, multiple coordinate transformations, and 2 types of Gauss integration.

Comment: I assume, that you already know the right indices? in other words you know the relation of New Index to Old Index?

Comment: I don't know the relationship. That's what I'm trying to find.

Answer (score 0):

Lets see if I understand the problem correctly:

You have a `Matrix` (call it `a`) of size `N x 4N` and you want to create a matrix (call it `b`) of size `2N x 2N`.

Element of `a` are defined by the set `(i,j,k,l)` such that:

```
a = f(1,1,1,1) f(1,1,2,1) f(1,2,1,1) f(1,2,2,1) ... f(N,2,2,1)
    f(1,1,1,2) f(1,1,2,2) f(1,2,1,2) f(1,2,2,2) ... f(N,2,2,2)
    f(1,1,1,3) f(1,1,2,3) f(1,2,1,3) f(1,2,2,3) ... f(N,2,2,3)
    f(1,1,1,4) f(1,1,2,4) f(1,2,1,4) f(1,2,2,4) ... f(N,2,2,4)
    ...
    f(1,1,1,N) f(1,1,2,N) f(1,2,1,N) f(1,2,2,N) ... f(N,2,2,N)
```

Now you want `b` such that:

```
b = f(1,1,1,1) f(1,1,2,1) f(1,1,1,2) f(1,1,2,2) ... f(1,1,2,N)
    f(1,2,1,1) f(1,2,2,1) f(1,2,1,2) f(1,2,2,2) ... f(1,2,2,N)
    f(2,1,1,1) f(2,1,2,1) f(2,1,1,2) f(2,1,2,2) ... f(2,1,2,N)
    f(2,2,1,1) f(2,2,2,1) f(2,2,1,2) f(2,2,2,2) ... f(2,2,2,N)
    ...
    f(N,2,1,N) f(N,2,2,N) f(N,2,1,N) f(N,2,2,N) ... f(N,2,2,N)
```

---

It above is correct then all you need to do is:

```
b = zeros(2*N);
b(:, 1:2:end) = a(:, 1:2:end)';
b(:, 2:2:end) = a(:, 2:2:end)';
```

---

Example:

```
n = 5;
a = 1:(4*n*n);
a = reshape(a, n, 4*n);

b = zeros(2*n);
b(:, 1:2:end) = a(:, 1:2:end)';
b(:, 2:2:end) = a(:, 2:2:end)';
```

Output:

```
a =

 Columns 1 through 13:

     1     6    11    16    21    26    31    36    41    46    51    56    61
     2     7    12    17    22    27    32    37    42    47    52    57    62
     3     8    13    18    23    28    33    38    43    48    53    58    63
     4     9    14    19    24    29    34    39    44    49    54    59    64
     5    10    15    20    25    30    35    40    45    50    55    60    65

 Columns 14 through 20:

    66    71    76    81    86    91    96
    67    72    77    82    87    92    97
    68    73    78    83    88    93    98
    69    74    79    84    89    94    99
    70    75    80    85    90    95   100

b =

     1     6     2     7     3     8     4     9     5    10
    11    16    12    17    13    18    14    19    15    20
    21    26    22    27    23    28    24    29    25    30
    31    36    32    37    33    38    34    39    35    40
    41    46    42    47    43    48    44    49    45    50
    51    56    52    57    53    58    54    59    55    60
    61    66    62    67    63    68    64    69    65    70
    71    76    72    77    73    78    74    79    75    80
    81    86    82    87    83    88    84    89    85    90
    91    96    92    97    93    98    94    99    95   100
```